# Python Libxml2 parseFile intermittently fails after OS upgrade

Tags: python, libxml2

We have a set of legacy python web applications that have been running on a Debian Lenny (production) server for years.  We have recently cloned that server and upgraded the clone to Wheezy.  The web applications work fine most of the time on the new server, however the calls to python libxml2.parseFile occassionally exception out, (preventing us from cutting over from the Lenny box to the Wheezy box).

**Some notes**

1. The parseFile failures do not start occurring immediately after apache is restarted. You have to start using the web applications and after some time (minutes or longer) the parseFile failures start to occur.  When they do start to occur, restarting apache seems to temporarily clear out whatever is interfering with parseFile's being able to access/read a file.
2. The failures seem to occur randomly across the different web applications and different pages (hence, different xsl files). They are not isolated to a specific set of xsl files.
3. While clicking around in one of our web apps, when you visit a page and parseFile fails, at that point if you refresh the page, parseFile works and the page renders correctly.
4. We did try using lxml (2.3.2-1) instead of the standard python bindings to libxml2 and got what appears to be the same issue on the call to etree.parse

**Configuration**

The web applications are using mod_python, (unfortunately it's not really an option right now for them to be converted to using mod_wsgi).

**Old server**

```
- Debian Lenny 
- Apache compiled with prefork 
- mod_python 3.3.1 
- python 2.5       
- libxml2  (2.6.32.dfsg-5+lenny5) 
- libxslt1.1 (1.1.24-2)  
- python-libxml2    (2.6.32.dfsg-5+lenny5) 
- python-libxslt1 (1.1.24-2)
```

**New server**

```
- Debian Wheezy
- Apache compiled with prefork
- mod_python 3.3.1
- python 2.7
- libxml2  (2.8.0+dfsg1-7+nmu3)
- libxslt1  (1.1.26-14.1)
- python-libxml2  (2.8.0+dfsg1-7+nmu3)
- python-libxslt1  (1.1.26-14.1)
```

Any ideas on what might be going on?  It seems to me the multi-threaded issues would not apply, since apache is compiled with MPM prefork - would that be correct or am I mistaken about that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do your Apache instances run any other module which might use *libxml2*, e.g. *mod_php* or *mod_perl*? What's the exact error message?